# Два одинаковых ключа

Tags: mysql, sql

Имеется такой запрос в базу данных:

```
select *
from `queue`
    left join `clients` on `clients`.`id` = `queue`.`client_id`
where `queue`.`user_id` = '11'
    and `queue`.`user_id` is not null
    and `finished` = '0'
```

Но после left join ключ id из таблицы, к которой присоединяю, заменяется на ключ таблицы, которую присоединяю. Есть решение без переименовывания ключей?

Comment: На каком диалекте запрос?

Comment: Ну если я правильно понял вопрос, mysql

Comment: Добавте метку mysql. Добавте вместо "*" поля, которые вас интересуют.

Comment: Дело в том, что используя функция laravel hasMany по ключу, если буду указывать поля - не будет работать поиск по ключу. К тому же нужны поле первой таблицы id

Comment: `where queue.user_id = '11' and queue.user_id is not null` Второе условие бессмысленно, его можно удалить из запроса. `ключ id из таблицы к которой присоединяю заменяется на ключ таблицы которую присоединяю` Интересно, как Вы их различаете, если они равны? или Вы хотите сказать, что для записей из queue, которым нет соответствия в clients, выводится queue.client_id значение Null?

Answer (score 0):

Можно задать алиас для поля `clients.id` или не выбирать его вообще, но остальные необходимые поля из таблицы `clients` нужно указать явно:

```
select Q.*, C.id as c_id, C.поле1, C.поле2, C...
from queue Q
left join clients C on C.id = Q.client_id
where Q.user_id = '11' and Q.finished = '0';
```